# How to handle certificate in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, twisted.internet, crossbar

I have an existing code in Python Autobahn which connects to a Crossbar server using WS. I want to make it work on WSS.
I have changed Crossbar, and it is working fine. I have tested it using Javascript Autobahn. However, the Python part doesn't connect to Crossbar with the change of protocol.

Although the certificate used in Crossbar server is a DigiCert certified one; but my guess is that the problem is related to the certificate. As I tried checking the certificate using this [procedure](https://docs.twisted.org/en/twisted-15.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#connecting-to-public-servers);

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from twisted.internet import defer, endpoints, protocol, ssl, task, error

def main(reactor, host, port=443):
    options = ssl.optionsForClientTLS(hostname=host.decode('utf-8'))
    port = int(port)

    class ShowCertificate(protocol.Protocol):
        def connectionMade(self):
            self.transport.write(b"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
            self.done = defer.Deferred()
        def dataReceived(self, data):
            certificate = ssl.Certificate(self.transport.getPeerCertificate())
            print("OK:", certificate)
            self.transport.abortConnection()
        def connectionLost(self, reason):
            print("Lost.")
            if not reason.check(error.ConnectionClosed):
                print("BAD:", reason.value)
            self.done.callback(None)

    return endpoints.connectProtocol(
        endpoints.SSL4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port, options),
        ShowCertificate()
    ).addCallback(lambda protocol: protocol.done)

task.react(main, sys.argv[1:])
```

it fails.

```
('BAD:', Error([('SSL routines', 'SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'certificate verify failed')],))
```

I have already installed the “`service_identity`” and “`idna`” packages from PyPI, as the link suggests.

I am trying to either help Twisted to verify the certificate or bypass the verification process.

Comment: What version of Python and Twisted are you using?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone It's Python 2.7.3 and Twisted 15.0.0.

Comment: Ah, that's difficult.  I'm not even sure how to set up a Python 2.7.3 environment on any modern system.  It wouldn't surprise me if the issue is that the SSL client library in that environment is just not compatible with the TLS servers that folks run nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Twisted couldn't verify the certificate. So, manually injecting the key/cert files made the change:

```
 endpoints.SSL4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port, ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory("key.pem",                                           "cert.pem")),
```

However, if the key/cert files are not available, veritication can be simply turned off (not secure, though):

```
endpoints.SSL4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port, ssl.CertificateOptions(verify=False)),
```